# Streaming data from an Android device to a PC via USB

Tags: android, c++, stream, usb, driver

I need to stream a set of numbers, 6 floats, from an android device to a PC, to which it is connected by a USB cable. All the solutions I have found proposes using a WiFi connection. However, I have found that the latency caused by this is not acceptable. As such I have decided that I am going to hire someone to integrate the components, thus enabling direct communication. Until then, however, I want to try a variety of devices to see what works and the quickest way to "Integrate" two devices is by allowing them to share a (US)Buss. However, this is the one field I have zero experience with.

Do you make a socket and treat the connection as a network connection or is there another fancier way to achieve what I want? I have seen some talk about making a device driver for this purpose and I do not feel like crashing my OS 500 times again. I find it hard to believe that the android devices do not have some kind of driver already made that I can exploit.

The android code is written in Java, but it could be changed depending on what people suggest. The main chunk of mys system lies on the PC and is written in C++.

I need the latency of the stream to be as low as possible since the entire system needs to be as real time as possible. The limit is 15 ms between data acquisition on the device and the rendering of the simulation on the PC.

TL/DR: I need to stream data from a program on an android device to a PC with as little latency as possible; i.e. one way communication. As long as I can stream bytes I can design protocols and translate the bytes on the receiving end. My global cap is 15 ms and I need to stream continually updated 6 floats. What is the best way to achieve this?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I don't know about the latency stuff, but have you seen AOAP -> https://source.android.com/accessories/protocol.html ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using the ADB brigde and it seems to be stable and fast enough for our purposes. All we had to do was to open a socket and connect with TCP. For some reason it fails when we try to connect with UDP, but I assume this might be due to ignorence on our part.

Answer (score 0):

Raw USB is probably not the way to go. USB is a device-oriented specification and cannot be used in a general send-arbitrary-bytes-across-a-wire way.

If Wi-Fi really is too slow, you could try purchasing an Android-compatible USB-Ethernet adaptor and connecting the device to the computer via a wired network connection, which might reduce the latency. Android recognises many types of these adaptors and you communicate over the network connection in the same way as other networks.

Comment: After a lot of testing we managed to get the ADB bridge to work reliably and responsively. We will go for that for the time being at least.